# Global Variable Using Twig Extension

Tags: php, twig, symfony

http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html
Documentation mentiones that I can define global variables.

But `\Twig_Extension` does not seems to have method that I can override in order to create global variables.

Does anybody knows how can I create global variable using the Twig extension?

Comment: Have you tried the Twig_Environment's `addGlobal()` method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `getGlobals` function was deprecated, if you really want to re-enable this feature you have to implement from the interface `Twig_Extension_GlobalsInterface` as well,

```
class MyTwigExtensions extends \Twig_Extension implements \Twig_Extension_GlobalsInterface {
    public function getGlobals() {
         //...
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'MyTwigExtensions';
    }
}
```

[documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/advanced.html#id1)